# JavaScript programme

Tags: javascript

I am putting an interactive java script form whereas the the out put is getting confused with switch case. Kindly help me:  It is pipe weight calculation.

Pipe sizes: 100mm, 150 mm, 200 mm, 250mm up to 1000mm
For each pipe the pressure class varies: PN3, PN6 and PN9
For each pressure class the stiffness varies: SN124 and SN256

For given Pipes size, pressure class and stiffness class - the weight will be different.  To arrive the out put - I am using the switch case, which is very lengthy and time consuming. Any body can help me in solving the java script so that same will be put in the HTML file.

This is the code I have, but I think there must be a better way to do it.

What's a better way?

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function CalculateSum(Atext, Btext, Ctext,form)
{
var A = parseFloat(Atext);
var B = parseFloat(Btext);
var C = parseFloat(Ctext);

switch (true){
case (A == 100 && B == 3  && C == 124): K =21.4; L=102; M =55; break ;
case (A == 100 && B == 3  && C == 256): K =21.9; L=125; M=49;  break ;
case (A == 100 && B == 3  && C == 512): K =22.2; L=133; M=45;  break ;
case (A == 100 && B == 6  && C == 124): K =42.9; L=139; M=41;  break ;
case (A == 100 && B == 6  && C == 256): K =42.78;L=141; M=39;  break ;
case (A == 100 && B == 6  && C == 512): K =43.01;L=144; M=37;  break ;
case (A == 100 && B == 9  && C == 124): K =54.84;L=148; M=34;  break ;
case (A == 100 && B == 9  && C == 256): K =55.02;L=152; M=31;  break ;
case (A == 100 && B == 9  && C == 512): K =56.90;L=157; M=29;  break ;
case (A == 150 && B == 3  && C == 124): K =39.4; L=164; M=25;  break ;
....
......
.......
break ;
}
    form.Ans1.value = K  + "   Kg/Rmt"; 
    form.Ans1.value = L  + "   Rmt";
    form.Ans1.value = M  + "   Nos";

}
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Second TheZ's comment. Include existing code. Also, how are the pressure class and stiffness values defined?

Comment: <P>Enter Pipe dia: 
<select name="input_A"  >
<option value="100">20 mm
<option value="150">25 mm
......
.....
</select></p>


<P>Enter Pressure class: 
<select name="input_B"  >
<option value="3"> 3 Kg
<option value="6"> 6 Kg
<option value="9"> 9 Kg
</select></p>


<P>Enter Stiffness class: 
<select name="input_C"  >

<option value="124"> SN124
<option value="256"> SN256
<option value="512"> SN512
</select></p>

Comment: @guruje: Again, if you want to update/improve your question, use the "edit" link under the question, don't post a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you can't calculate `K` from `A`, `B`, and `C`, which would of course be best. Assuming that's the case:

Your way works. It's an unusual way of using `switch`, but it's valid in JavaScript. (Not in most other languages.)

The other way to do it would be to have a table as a nested bunch of objects, and look the values up in the table:

```
var Values = {
    // Values for A
    100: {
        // Values for B when A = 100
        3: {
            // Values for C when A == 100 and B == 3
            124: 21.4,
            256: 21.9,
            512: 22.2
        },
        6: {
            // Values for C when A == 100 and B == 6
            124: 42.9,
            256: 42.78,
            512: 43.01
        },
        9: {
            // Values for C when A == 100 and B == 9
            124: 54.84,
            256: 55.02,
            512:39.4
        }
    },
    150: {
        // Values for B when A = 150
        3: {
            // Values for C when A == 150 and B == 3
            124: 39.4
        }
    }
};
```

I'm not sure that makes the data more readable/maintainable, but it's quite quick to use, and you *can* write it a bit more concisely (see the end of the answer); I wanted to include the comments above.

`CalculateSum` ends up looking like this:

```
function CalculateSum(Atext, Btext, Ctext,form)
{
    var A = parseFloat(Atext);
    var B = parseFloat(Btext);
    var C = parseFloat(Ctext);
    var entry;

    // Get the top-level entry for A
    entry = Values[A];
    if (entry) {
        // We have one, get its entry for this value of B
        entry = entry[B];
        if (entry) {
            // We have one, get _its_ entry for C
            entry = entry[C];
        }
    }

    if (typeof entry === "number") {  
        form.Ans.value = entry  + "   Kg/Rmt"; 
    }
    else {
        // Didn't find it
    }
}
```

Or as Deestan points out in the comments, you can shorten that a bit if you're not doing this in a hyper-tight loop you run hundreds of thousands of times (which I'm guessing you're not):

```
function CalculateSum(Atext, Btext, Ctext,form)
{
    var A = parseFloat(Atext);
    var B = parseFloat(Btext);
    var C = parseFloat(Ctext);
    var K;

    // Get the entry from our tables
    K = Values[A] && Values[A][B] && Values[A][B][C];

    if (typeof K === "number") {  
        form.Ans.value = K  + "   Kg/Rmt"; 
    }
    else {
        // Didn't find it
    }
}
```

(There I changed `entry` to `K` because we never store anything but the final value in it.)

And here's the more concise `Values`:

```
var Values = {
    100: {
        3: { 124: 21.4,  256: 21.9,  512: 22.2  },
        6: { 124: 42.9,  256: 42.78, 512: 43.01 },
        9: { 124: 54.84, 256: 55.02, 512: 39.4  }
    },
    150: {
        3: { 124: 39.4 }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much - is there other way in simple form  using j query / json . Because, there is lot of entries (i.e 135 different values).  Also i do not like to use SWITCH statement of old style? please help.

Comment: Or if you want to shave off a few lines: `entry = Values[A] && Values[A][B] && Values[A][B][C]`

Comment: It is better, if lines are short

Comment: @guruje: Yes indeed. Note that Deestan's change requires that the engine look-up `Values[A]` three times (in the successful case) and that value's entry for `B` twice, which is repeated, unnecessary work. The engine may or may not optimize that for you, but unless you're doing this in a tight loop, hundreds of thousands of times, or the `Values` object has thousands and thousands of properties on it, the extra lookups don't matter.

Comment: @Deestan: Yes indeed. I wanted individual steps so I could comment what was going on, but I should have included that originally. Have now, thanks.

Comment: I do agree with @Deestan as well as @ Crowder comments. What I request you, please provide the alternates in JSON / AJAX or other ways.  As I am not efficient in JavaScript programming ..... Please sir.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder A fair point regarding the efficiency.  But, note that the reassignment of `entry` is also an operation.  I tried profiling some code using each of the methods in Chrome, and they came out even.

Comment: @Deestan: Property lookup and variable assignment are quite different ops. But yes, I think you'd have to have thousands of properties in the object for it matter (hash table lookups).

Comment: Thank you very much for simple presentation. Where I should mention the "K" which is the answer.  OR instead of "values" shall I put "K"

Comment: @guruje: `form.Ans.value = entry  + "   Kg/Rmt";` doesn't make that clear?

Comment: Because,  once the weight is known, the  volume & other details are arrived after "K" is known. hence, the value of "K" is important

Comment: @guruje: `entry` ***is*** `K`. Look at the code. Try to understand it. Walk through how it works. See where the values you had in your switch where you said `K = 22.2` or whatever have become entries in `Values`. Surely it was obvious that `entry` is K? I mean, your original line was `form.Ans.value = K + " Kg/Rmt"` and I updated that to use `entry` instead.

Comment: Thank you sir for detailed explanation.  Shall I put in the else{ "not in Range"}